# How do I authenticate cloud functions using default service account?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, service-accounts

I have a default service account(projectId@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) in my project. I want to use this service account for authneticating my cloud functions. My server side of the project is in nodejs with firebase google cloud functions.

Everytime a cloud function gets called, I am calling the below function initApp and then after initializind the cloud function code gets executed.

```
const { initializeApp, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app')
module.exports.initApp = () => {
    const keyFile = require('../keyfile.json')
    const id = keyFile.project_id

    initializeApp({
      storageBucket: `${id}.appspot.com`,
      databaseURL: `https://${id}.firebaseio.com`,
      credential: cert(keyFile),
    })
}
```

This is my normal flow. Now I want to use this service account for calling the cloud function.

I have tried it through shell commands. First, I added cloud function invoker for the cloud functions as the service account. I set the credentials and ran

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token projectId@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

I passed the token generated as Authorization header for the cloud function call.

Is this the correct way? If yes how do I do it programatically? If it is not the correct method, how do I achive it?